# DataSet ReadXml ignores the attributes with prefix

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing, dataset

I have the following xml code which I want to read into a dataset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<jlqn:Root xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:jlqn="http://jlqn/1.0">
  <element xsi:type="jlqn:Processor" name="test1" processor="test">
    <metadata name="Removed" value="False" />
    <task id="6">
      <entry id="8" entry="" />
    </task>
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="jlqn:Processor" name="test1" processor="test" id="1">
    <metadata name="Removed" value="True" />
    <metadata name="Removed1" value="Removed1" />
  </element>
  <element xsi:type="jlqn:Processor" name="test1" processor="test" id="3">
    <metadata name="Removed" value="False" />
    <task id="45" name="">
      <metadata />
      <entry id="10" entry="">
        <metadata />
      </entry>
    </task>
  </element>
  <element name="test" />
</jlqn:Root>
```

I use the following C# code

```
  DataSet newTable = new DataSet();
            newTable.ReadXml(@"F:\QVT\runtime-EclipseApplication\dr5\HJYU.jlqn");
```

But when I check the dataset , I notice all the attributes with prefix are not read ..such as this : xsi:type="jlqn:Processor"

what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The XML references an namespace prefix "xsi", but it is not defined. Change the root element to:

```
<jlqn:Root xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:jlqn="http://jlqn/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Once I did this, I got the following tables and columns:

```
Root
  Root_Id
  version
element
  element_Id
  name
  processor
  id
  Root_Id
metadata
  name
  value
  element_Id
task
  metadata
  task_Id
  id
  name
  element_Id
entry
  metadata
  id
  entry
  task_Id
```

That is the output from:

```
DataSet newTable = new DataSet();
newTable.ReadXml(@"XMLFile1.xml");

foreach(DataTable table in newTable.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(table.TableName);

    foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + column.ColumnName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but still "xsi:type="jlqn:Processor" is not being populated into the dataset !